# Updating value in ng-repeat based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-change

I'm building a table using ng-repeat to display some information. One of the columns displayed is a 'Weight' column. We store all the weight in kilograms in the database, but need to give the user an option to display the weight in pounds.

I have a dropdown where the user is able to select the weight unit, and on ng-change i'm trying to update the table. However, i'm having trouble getting it to work.

Here is a look at my change function (full example in JSFiddle):

```
 $scope.ConvertWeights = function () {
        if ($scope.schedWeight.ID == "I") {
            $scope.items.Weight = $scope.items.Weight * 2.2046;
        } else {
            $scope.items.Weight = $scope.items.Weight / 2.2046;
        }

    }
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6404/) of what I'm currently attempting. If anyone has ran into a similar situation, I'd appreciate any advice on how to get this working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your function

```
$scope.ConvertWeights = function () {
    if ($scope.schedWeight.ID == "I") {
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item){
            item.Weight = item.Weight * 2.2046;
        })
    } else {
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item){
            item.Weight = item.Weight / 2.2046;
        })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.items is your item collection (an array). You were probably trying to write:

```
$scope.ConvertWeights = function () {
    if ($scope.schedWeight.ID == "I") {
        for (var i in $scope.items)
            $scope.items[i].Weight = $scope.items[i].Weight * 2.2046;
    } else {
        for (var i in $scope.items)
            $scope.items[i].Weight = $scope.items[i].Weight / 2.2046;
    }
}
```

You need to modify the Weight property on each element, not on the collection itself.